# Vue router can't validate user

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Some of my app routes are restricted for admins only for that I've added `requiresAdmin: true,` to those routes meta but somehow I doesn't prevent other users of accessing those routes.

## Code

PS: I've commented parts for better understanding.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        // ADMIN ROUTES
        {
            path: '/export',
            name: 'ExportXML',
            component: ExportXML,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true,
                requiresAdmin: true,  // only admins can see this page
                layout: 'admin',
                name: 'Export XML',
            }
        },
    ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
            next({
                name: 'login'
            })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
        // first make sure getter can get logged user data
        if (store.getters.loggedUser && !store.getters.loggedUser === undefined) {
            // then check if loged user "type" is admin (any other possebilities are denied)
            if (!store.getters.loggedUser.type === 'admin' || store.getters.loggedUser.type === '' || store.getters.loggedUser.type === null || store.getters.loggedUser.type === undefined || store.getters.loggedUser.type === 'worker') {
                next({
                    name: 'dashboard'
                })
            } else {
                next()
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        next()
    }
});


router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        document.title = to.pageTitle || 'Testing Site';
    });
});

export default router;
```

Any idea why for example my user with type of `worker` still can see `exports` page while is restricted for admins only?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here

```js
if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
  if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
    next({
      name: 'login'
    })
  } else {
    next() //  specifically here
  }
}
```

This skips any more checks once you've validated that the user is logged in.

You need to move the next `if` block checking for admins into that `else` block above, replacing the `next()`. In fact, you could clean this up by using `return` to exit the processing when required

```js
if (to.matched.some(({ meta }) => meta.requiresAuth) && !store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
  return next({ name: 'login' }) // not logged in, redirect to login
}
if (to.matched.some(({ meta }) => meta.requiresAdmin)
    && store.getters.loggedUser.type !== 'admin') {
  return next({ name: 'dashboard' }) // not admin, redirect to dashboard
}
next() // otherwise, everything is fine
```

[image: Edit modest-meninsky-w3u2z]

Comment: but i think this will forbid other routes which doesn't need admin access isn't it?

Comment: @mafortis I've added a better example

Comment: I get this `InternalError: too much recursion`

Comment: @mafortis I don't see any recursion in any of this code or the code in your question so I'm really not sure where that comes from

Comment: else needed i've fixed it like this (still testing) https://ibb.co/NYBDnZV

Comment: No, that just introduces the exact same problem you started with

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: @mafortis I've added a CodeSandbox demo and you can see it works fine. There must be some other code that you haven't shown that is trying to do something incorrect

Comment: Honestly i don't know what to say, your sample code return error and when I add `else` parts it works just fine, i understand that with else part code back to its basic version but somehow it works (really confused :D)

Answer (score 0):

check my comment in the code

```
if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) { // <== problem in condition
        next({
            name: 'login'
        })
    } else {
        next().  //  this line is always executed if a user is logged in. so any any logged in user can visit url in your application
    }
}
```

one possible solution may be

```
if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) { 
        next({
            name: 'login'
        })
    } else {
        
        // then check if loged user "type" is admin (any other possebilities are denied)
        if (!store.getters.loggedUser.type === 'admin' || store.getters.loggedUser.type === '' || store.getters.loggedUser.type === null || store.getters.loggedUser.type === undefined || store.getters.loggedUser.type === 'worker') {
            next({
                name: 'dashboard'
            })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
    
}
else {
  next()
}
```

Comment: i think you just copy paste my code i didn't find any difference

Comment: problem lies with the condition ```if (!store.getters.isLoggedIn) {}``` . check my edited answer with comment on code.